# What does closest pixels mean in a digital image?

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I need to apply some simple filter to a digital image. It says that for each pixel, I need to get the median of the closest pixels. I wonder since the image for example is M x M. What are the closest pixels? Are they just left, right, upper, lower pixel, and the current pixel (in total 5 pixels) or I need to take into account all the 9 pixels in a 3x3 area?

Follow up question: what if I want the median of the N closest pixels (N = 3)?

Thanks.

Comment: Use all 9 for a 3x3 median filter.

Comment: Thanks. Then what if I want the median of the N closest pixels (N=3)?

Comment: You find the 9 neighbours (including the centre pixel), sort them by value, and take the fifth one as the value to replace the centre pixel. Just change the numbers for different kernel sizes and if it's an even number, use the average of the middle two values after sorting.

Comment: If you want a higher order N, just increase your search area. So check the 8 neighbors around your image, and the 16 around those, and the 24 around those. Think of it like an increasing radius.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to apply median filter to a sample image. By definition of median for an image, you need to look at the neighboring pixels and find the median. There are two definitions which is important, one is the image size which is m*n and the other filter kernel size which x*y. If the kernel size is of size 3*3, you will need to look at 9 pixels like this:

[image: 3*3 median filtering]

Find the median of a odd number of pixels is easy, consider you have three 3 pixels x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub> and x<sub>3</sub> arranged in ascending order of their values. The median of this set of pixels is x<sub>2</sub>.

Now, if you have an even number of pixels, usually the average of two pixels lying midway is computed. For example, say there are 4 pixels x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub> and x<sub>4</sub> arranged in ascending order of their values. The median of this set of pixels is (x<sub>1</sub>+x<sub>2</sub>)/2.